# Plot negative on logarithmic axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I followed this example and it works great for my data (https://r-graphics.org/recipe-axes-axis-log). Except I am also trying to add standard deviations and for one of the variables, the standard deviation is bigger than the mean. The figure just plots the top error bar but not the bottom. How can I add the error bar for Sample 5?

```
 Sample <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 Fe <- c(418, 592, 228, 351, 23880)
 sd <- c(269, 538, 187, 236, 36577)

 df <- data.frame(Sample, Fe, sd)
 df

 (plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sample, y = Fe, ymin = Fe - sd, ymax = Fe + sd)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size=3, stat = "identity") + 
 geom_errorbar(aes(width = 0.1), stat = "identity") +
 scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                   breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pmax(0, .)` it:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Sample, y = Fe, ymin = pmax(0, Fe - sd), ymax = Fe + sd)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size=3, stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(width = 0.1), stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l")
```

[image: ggplot, last error bar goes to or below 0]

Or you can use a smaller number and *see* the lower end of that error bar, though that might suggest a present value that isn't ...

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Sample, y = Fe, ymin = pmax(1, Fe - sd), ymax = Fe + sd)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size=3, stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(width = 0.1), stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l")
```

[image: ggplot, last error bar stops just above the horizontal 0 axis]

Using much smaller values will continue to squish the other errors a little tighter as the y-axis tries to adjust.